# Tableau layout for multiple charts on one worksheet

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have 15 pie charts on one worksheet (one for each year since 2006). At the minute I can either have them in a vertical line or a horizontal line but I want to have them in 3 rows of 5, how do I go about doing that?

Thanks in advance (from a Tableau newbie) !

Comment: A Dashboard will allow you to provide layout.  You will need one chart per worksheet in order to lay them out in a Dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for could be a tecnqique that consists in creating two additional calculated field for row_indicator and column_indicator.

So assuming you have a pie for each product_category you could create something like this for rows:

```
if prdocuct_category in ('a','b','c','d','e') then 1
elseif prdocuct_category in ('f','g','h','i','j') then 2
else 3
end
```

Once you've done the same for columns, you can use those two fields in the worksheet as first field in row/column shelf.

Otherwise, you can check the small multiple technique which is more or less the same and splits your by in groups according to the square root.

Check this tecnique in this video:
https://www.vizwiz.com/2016/03/tableau-tip-tuesday-how-to-create-small.html